# How to animate image change under scrollViewDidScroll in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal `CollectionView` in my project where by the center index of the `CollectionView` my `ImageView` image changes on `scrollViewDidScroll`. So i have tried to perform a **transition** effect on my image change. But it's not working may be because there is not enough delay. So what could be the work around? This is my code:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.votingimageView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {

                    self.votingimageView.image = self.imageArray[self.findCenterIndex()]


            }, completion: nil)
```

I have tried to add it on `scrollViewDidEndDragging` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` where the animation works but i wanted to change the image on every index change which is not working! For example if i want to go from 1 to 10, i want my imageview image get changed on every index change.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2 solution of your question

first animate in `cellForRows~` func every time when cells were reused show animation only once per calling func `cellForRows`

second make page for your collectionView like below

```
var page: Int { 
    didSet {
        //update cell's animation when really page was changed
        if page != oldValue {
            //call animation for page 1~10 (your example)
        }
    }
}
```

and update your page in `scrollVidDidScroll`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    page = Int(round(Double(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Double(scrollView.bounds.size.width)))
}
```

if you scroll collectionView index 0 to 10

page changed to 0,1,2,3,4, ... 9,10 per page called once animation occur

Comment: i don't get your second point! can u explain it. Beside i have already called my animation code under scrollVidDidScroll